# What and How does Relay and GraphQL interfaces work?

Tags: graphql, relayjs

we define a type in GraphQL like this:

```
  const GraphQLTodo = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Todo',
  fields: {
    id: globalIdField('Todo'),
    text: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (obj) => obj.text,
    },
    complete: {
      type: GraphQLBoolean,
      resolve: (obj) => obj.complete,
    },
  },
  interfaces: [nodeInterface], // what is this?
});
```

and I've read there is GraphQLInterfaceType - is more suitable when the types are basically the same but some of the fields are different(is this something like a foreign key?)

and in Relay we get the nodefield and nodeInterface with nodeDefinitions:

```
const {nodeInterface, nodeField} = nodeDefinitions(
  (globalId) => {
    const {type, id} = fromGlobalId(globalId); 
    if (type === 'Todo') {
      return getTodo(id);
    } else if (type === 'User') {
      return getUser(id);
    }
    return null;
  },
  (obj) => {
    if (obj instanceof Todo) {
      return GraphQLTodo;
    } else if (obj instanceof User) {
      return GraphQLUser;
    }
    return null;
  }
);
```

The docs and samples only used one on interfaces: [] //it's an array. but when do I need to use many interfaces? I am just confused on what it is, I've read a lot about it(don't know if my understanding is correct), just can't seem to wrap it in my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `GraphQLInterfaceType` is one way GraphQL achieves **polymorphism**, i.e. types that consist of multiple *object types*. For example, suppose you have two base object types, `Post` and `Comment`. Suppose you want a field that could get a list of *both comments and posts*. Conveniently, both these types have an `id`, `text`, and `author` field. This is the perfect use case for an interface type. An interface type is a group of shared fields, and it can be **implemented by** any object type which possesses those fields. So we create an `Authored` interface and say the `Comment` and `Post` implement this interface. By placing this `Authored` type on a GraphQL field, that field can resolve either posts or comments (or a heterogeneous list of both types).

But wait, `Post` and `Comment` accept an **array of interfaces**. I could pass multiple interfaces here. Why? Since the requirement for implementing an interface is possession of all the fields in that interface, there is no reason why any object type can't implement *multiple interfaces*. To draw from your example, the `Node` interface in Relay only needs `id`. Since our `Post` and `Comment` have `id`, they could implement *both* `Node` and `Authored`. But many other types will likely implement `Node`, ones that aren't part of `Authored`.

This makes your object types much more re-usable. If you assign interfaces to your field instead of object types, you can easily add new possible types to the fields in your schema as long as you stick to these agreed-upon interfaces.